# TypeScript add kebab case types form actual camel case keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typing

this is an example input interface

```js
export interface CssProperties {
    alignContent: number | string | null;
    alignItems: number | string | null;
    alignSelf: number | string | null;
    alignmentBaseline: number | string | null;
}
```

the result type should look like this.

-> adds kebab case types

```js
export interface CssProperties {
    align-content: number | string | null;
    alignContent: number | string | null;
    align-items: number | string | null;
    alignItems: number | string | null;
    align-self: number | string | null;
    alignSelf: number | string | null;
    alignment-baseline: number | string | null;
    alignmentBaseline: number | string | null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking to get hyphenated CSS properties added to `React.CSSProperties`, you can do this via module augmentation.

Create a file in your root called `css.d.ts` and use this content:

```
declare module "csstype" {
  interface Properties extends PropertiesHyphen {}
}
```

More documentation here:
https://github.com/frenic/csstype#usage

This works because react uses `csstype` under the hood for its `CSSProperties` type.

Answer (score 17):

### UPDATED FOR TS4.5+

Now that TypeScript supports [tail recursion elimination on conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) we can write `Kebab<T>` in a straightforward way that should handle strings up to ~1000 characters:

```
type Kebab<T extends string, A extends string = ""> =
    T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ?
    Kebab<R, `${A}${F extends Lowercase<F> ? "" : "-"}${Lowercase<F>}`> :
    A
```

This works by iterating character-by-character, and inserting a `"-"` before each character which is not already lowercase (so caseless characters like numbers will not get a dash before them), and then lowercasing each character.

Non-tail-recursive character-by-character iteration in TypeScript 4.5+, or any recursive type in TypeScript 4.4 and below hits recursion limits for modestly long strings, sometimes even strings of only twenty or so characters, and weird workarounds were required to handle longer strings.  But now we can handle string literals longer than I imagine anyone would reasonably need:

```
type Testing = Kebab<"itWasTheBestOfTimesItWasTheWorstOfTimesItWasTheAgeOfWisdomItWasTheAgeOfFoolishnessItWasTheEpochOfBeliefItWasTheEpochOfIncredulityItWasTheSeasonOfLightItWasTheSeasonOfDarknessItWasTheSpringOfHopeItWasTheWinterOfDespair">
// type Testing = "it-was-the-best-of-times-it-was-the-worst-of-times-it-was-the-age-of-wisdom-it-was-the-age-of-foolishness-it-was-the-epoch-of-belief-it-was-the-epoch-of-incredulity-it-was-the-season-of-light-it-was-the-season-of-darkness-it-was-the-spring-of-hope-it-was-the-winter-of-despair"
```

---

Now we can use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) (also a TS4.1 feature) to easily convert from an object with camelCase keys to one with kebab-case keys:

```
type KebabKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T as K extends string ? Kebab<K> : K]: T[K] };
```

---

Finally, let's try it out on your example:

```
export interface CssPropertiesCamel {
    alignContent: number | string | null;
    alignItems: number | string | null;
    alignSelf: number | string | null;
    alignmentBaseline: number | string | null;
}    

type CssPropertiesKebab = KebabKeys<CssPropertiesCamel>;
/* type CssPropertiesKebab = {
    "align-content": number | string | null;
    "align-items": number | string | null;
    "align-self": number | string | null;
    "alignment-baseline": number | string | null;
} */

export interface CssProperties extends CssPropertiesCamel, CssPropertiesKebab { }
```

Looks good!  We've turned `CssPropertiesCamel` into `CssPropertiesKebab`, and then `CssProperties` can just be a merged version of those two types.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hBGBDeAeAKlCAPYEB2AJgM5RHABOAlngOYA0UAgpjvsaRdTVALxQBE-AHy8AUFAlQM2XIRIADACQBvagDMI5KADEAvivWaoAJV3yoAfnGS4SVMYZLljfcu0tZ7ADIB7AO6aAMaIRBAo2iIWAvxQAFwCALT8rr4B5MGh4UJmIrHWEoyioqCQUhBkXLywCMgo-JTAAOohaAAWEABC5cAA8mpolAC25QCSTS3tjT7kZH0Dw0RjzURtEIw0EH2NlEQEPoNLE2sbfdo+PgA2O6145YvjK+0AomA+ga19XVcQaoePEC83h9fnhAuQIAQAK5XUB-VYAZQgIR8eD6XkoNFawDh7URyNRagAIohyABrW5Ee7LBFgKi0PoACR8kBxEG2eFw5D6hPKYEQlHIwlEAHphVAStA0N1Knx6sAEn4QglgO0EvBugkfGplUNygkGgqlSqIArpmRNdrgLqiPr5YqbcaEogNhaFTs9oNbYaHarnSatQk1OcrkQbncvfblaqIK93q71d9tQbI46Y0DXdQwRDoQ0QBGjarQvjXVdMfLkwWTUWiCjXQQSeTwxWfVXaVxXa1mSbm1GTX5qJy67z+YKihLqnY4CAiOgRHxlFAANowKDUKCkiAgLVSKAhWAeNgkMh07hRWy1GC5WAAXXiaGX16gugA3EVsK9yMBVxzNGpEIFoAAYUpAAFcgu0-ShykAxBhguKBlHyXdSzwQCUVkYB4jwSFBnVLQAB8OBPKBCOwi4LlfSRkIxPAxggQYiCwnC8JIojKlI6EKKQxAUMRC41CY3CjEI492KgMiuKoniaOGDkOhCCArluQSWJEzhaFYiTX10IpinAIDQPAyBIPKc94CqMypxnYCiDAiCrWg2DFKEV9hQAKnFfSoBsuzjIcogzKqRCqP4aSaDwBJAnQ-BgH4FThLYjSOPIyjJFClDbXoog4vE5iEtEpLcpSpD0pohJQn4nLsKEgjEu4ZLJLSsK8Fk+UkAq6gICqvLaoK+qiq43QoDc4U3ywD8vwHX9-wM2yjM0fyDzkbzDPsqCiBguCGB8+aTICmpzIXHSiiAA)

Comment: Your updated solution adds a "-" at the beginning of the word. You have to deal with the first letter scenario.

Comment: @Bernardo Maybe you're trying to convert `PascalCase` aka `UpperCamelCase` (capitalized) to `kebab-case`?  The use case here is `camelCase` aka `lowerCamelCase` (uncapitalized), which works fine with the solution as written.   If you have a different use case you might need a different solution.

Comment: any idea on how to do that using typescipt 4.0? For us migrating to a newer version is not an option at the moment

Comment: Given that template literal types weren't introduced until TS4.1, it is impossible to do anything like this in 4.0 or before.  If you have more such questions, please make a new post for them, since comments sections on older answers aren't great places to get engagement (and such comments could be deleted at any time anyway)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution I came to that uses a trampolining technique to defer the typescript type so it doesn't throw recursive type errors.

```js
export type KebabCase<S> = S extends `${infer C}${infer T}`
  ? KebabCase<T> extends infer U
    ? U extends string
      ? T extends Uncapitalize<T>
        ? `${Uncapitalize<C>}${U}`
        : `${Uncapitalize<C>}-${U}`
      : never
    : never
  : S
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another approach:

```js
export interface CssProperties {
    alignContent: number | string | null;
    alignItems: number | string | null;
    alignSelf: number | string | null;
    alignmentBaseline: number | string | null;
}

type ToCebab<T extends string> =
    T extends `align${infer Prefix}`
    ? `aling-${Uncapitalize<Prefix>}`
    : never;

type Result = {
    [P in keyof CssProperties as ToCebab<P>]: CssProperties[P]
} & CssProperties
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=18&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQGdCAFKCMNGBYQuAbwCg4W5MAbBAcyXwhWAoAXHCQBXALYAjNHAA%20cQjCjIu80WPbsA3M1YduSAJKoJhEeOmyFSlUjULxW3azaceAZWDt0FyTKh1W1V1Jx09FgMeCUEYACFMQm9kYD8rQJtlEMdNcIBfRkYYAE9KOAAVCHxgKUwpAB5yuFBUJAATOmD7AD44AF4IiuaQVo64AAMopAASemR0WTJgdAQQPPHBgH4Jg3sAWlmAVSRsTDAEGAMAL2B6pZWQbvXBi2AANzRdItK8ACVaTTwPoMQYAbRIiCQcAA1sBihB0ARiGQKFQaHREhUqjU6ndugBdEREUjkSiwdHg-GMPJwABkSJJqPJtEKjCAA)

[Template literal strings - Uncapitalize](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#uncapitalizestringtype)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the great answer of @jcalz, I made a modified version to make snake_case into kebab-case:

```
type KebabCase<
  T extends string,
  A extends string = ''
> = T extends `${infer P1}_${infer P2}${infer R}`
  ? KebabCase<R, `${A}${P1}-${P2}`>
  : `${A}${T}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt to solve problem to convert arbitrary string (that can contains '-', ' ' and '_' as separator) to kebab-case:

```
type TSeparator = ' ' | '_' | '-';

type TTailKebabCase<Str extends string, Processed extends string = ''> =
  Str extends TSeparator | ''
    ? Processed
    : Str extends `${infer Letter}${infer Tail}`
      ? Letter extends TSeparator
        ? TKebabCase<Tail, `${Processed}`, '-'>
        : TTailKebabCase<Tail, `${Processed}${Letter extends Lowercase<Letter> ? '' : '-'}${Lowercase<Letter>}`>
      : `${Processed}${Str}`;

export type TKebabCase<Str extends string, Processed extends string = '', Minus extends string = ''> =
  Str extends TSeparator | ''
    ? Processed
    : Str extends `${infer Letter}${infer Tail}`
      ? Letter extends TSeparator
        ? TKebabCase<Tail, Processed, Processed extends '' ? '' : '-'>
        : TTailKebabCase<Tail, `${Processed}${Minus}${Lowercase<Letter>}`>
      : `${Processed}${Minus}${Str}`;
```

This code may process some edge cases such as:

```
TKebabCase<'_abAc-'> -> 'ab-ac'
TKebabCase<'ab Ac '> -> 'ab-ac'
TKebabCase<'___ab__ aC--'> -> 'ab-a-c'
TKebabCase<'- - -'> -> ''
```

Also it can process long string (I tested at string with 150+ symbols).