# Styled Component: hover style passed in props

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a `StyledButton`, and I use it like this:

```
const StyledButton = styled.div<{
  hoverStyle?: CSSProperties
}>`
  color: black;
  background: blue;

  // What can I do here to apply the hoverStyle?
`

<StyledButton
  hoverStyle={{
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    color: 'white',
  }}
>
  My button
</StyledButton>
```

Are there any ways to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we provide individual values in extra styling props, but it is still definitely possible to provide a set of CSS rules (a CSSObject).

First you need to use an interpolation function to [adapt the style](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics?#adapting-based-on-props) based on runtime props:

```
const StyledButton = styled.div<{
  hoverStyle?: CSSProperties
}>`
  color: black;
  background: blue;

  // What can I do here to apply the hoverStyle?
  ${(props) => props.hoverStyle && inlineRules(props.hoverStyle)}
`
```

Here I used an `inlineRules` function to convert the CSSObject into a list of rules:

```
function inlineRules(rulesObj: CSSProperties) {
  return Object.entries(rulesObj).map(([property, value]) => `${property}: ${value};`).join('');
}
```

Then, based on the "hoverStyle" name of your styling prop, it sounds like these rules should be applied only on `:hover`, rather than being directly merged with the root styles of your `<div>`. In that case, you need to place them in a [nested block](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics?#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting), for which you can use the `&` ampersand keyword to refer to the self style:

> `&` a single ampersand refers to all instances of the component; it is used for applying broad overrides

```
  &:hover {
    ${(props) => props.hoverStyle && inlineRules(props.hoverStyle)}
  }
```

Live demo on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-brook-h515v7?file=/src/App.tsx

Note: CSS rules in styled-components actually use the normal "kebab-case" notation, whereas `CSSProperties` are defined in camelCase ("background-color" v.s. "backgroundColor" in your example). In the above demo, I used a template literal conversion type to convert them into kebab-case, based on [TypeScript add kebab case types form actual camel case keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66140451/typescript-add-kebab-case-types-form-actual-camel-case-keys)

Comment: Thank you bro. Yeah I thought and I was about to do that after having search pretty much on Google.