# An array of valid CSS property names in TypeScript, but hyphened

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I have a property in my component that is supposed to get an array of valid CSS properties:

```
interface MyComponentProps {
    cssProperties: (keyof CSSStyleDeclaration)[];
}

const MyComponent = ({ cssProperties }: MyComponentProps) => {
    //
}
```

The problem is that `CSSStyleDeclaration` stores styles as an object with property names in camel case. I need real CSS property values, hyphened. So `background-color` instead of `backgroundColor`. I know there's also `React.CSSProperties` type, but it uses camel-cased properties too, while allowing for unitless numeric values.

Is there a TypeScript type to use original, hyphened CSS property names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this library [csstype](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csstype/v/1.8.1) which is used by MUI, emotion and some other popular component libraries.

Which allows you to use the **hyphen** props

```
import CSS from "csstype";

interface MyComponentProps {
  cssProperties: (keyof CSS.PropertiesHyphen)[];
}

const MyComponent = ({ cssProperties }: MyComponentProps) => {
  //
}

<MyComponent cssProperties={["color", "background-color"]} />;
```

Comment: I'll have a look in a bit.

Comment: Okay, it works as expected, thanks. I was sure there must be a package for this!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Kebab` type available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66140779/6695924). *Camelcased* CSS properties will be transformed into *kebabcase*.

```
type Kebab<T extends string, A extends string = ""> =
    T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ?
    Kebab<R, `${A}${F extends Lowercase<F> ? "" : "-"}${Lowercase<F>}`> :
    A

type Props = {
    cssProps: Kebab<keyof React.CSSProperties>[];
}

const Component = (props: Props) => null;

const App = () => (
  <Component cssProps={['min-width']} />
);
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hBGBDeAeAKlCAPYEB2AJgM5RHABOAlngOYA0UAgpjvsaRdTVALxQBE-AHy8AUFAlQM2XIRIADACQBvagDMI5KADEAvivWaoAJV3yoAfnGS4SVMYZLljfcu0tZ7ADIB7AO6aAMaIRBAo2iIWAvxQAFwCALT8rr4B5MGh4UJmIrHWEoyiopQAtmA+5MAmEIiBVWrkPiVQAOTkNXUtANxFoJBQAAqNYCR8yvlQgUREQz4j8bbIKADWECA+atW1wAB0AMIAygezkJWUEERCANoAuj26RYE+eGRQe03lePhVfAAUYMMiPETkQAJS8ER4ACuABsYT1RE8XlVGGAwLwoL9wTwRL9rCh3mVnt9JtMQTxlFcWiVqAk-JQCMAABYtG66KAAeiEolBXSAA)

Comment: I thought about that, but I'd need to investigate whether `CSSStyleDeclaration` has some edge cases (pun!) where converting the case wouldn't convert to a CSS property. Also I'd like to make 100% sure there are no alternatives.

Comment: Also, it loses vendor prefixed properties, however I could live without them.

Comment: @RoboRobok According to the W3C standards all of the CSS properties are kebabcased. There should be not any problems with it, except vendor prefixes.

Comment: Thanks, I selected another answer as it uses less trickery :)